# Checkbox checked event is fired twice, on ionChange

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have this html :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let category of campaignCategories">
        <ion-checkbox
            class="campaign-filter-checkbox"
            [checked]="isChecked(category)"
            (ionChange)="selectCategory(category, $event)">
        </ion-checkbox>
        <ion-label>
            {{ category.name }}
        </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
```

My .ts :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initCategories();
}

initCategories() {
    this.campaignService.getCategoryList()
        .then((data: any) => {
            this.campaignCategories         = data;
            this.campaignCategoriesSearch   = data;
            this.campaignCategoriesChecked  = this.navParams.get('checkedCategories');
        })
        .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
}

selectCategory(category: CampaignCategoryInterface, ev) {
    if (ev.detail.checked) {
        if (!this.campaignCategoriesChecked.find(e => e.corporateCategoryId === category.corporateCategoryId)) {
            this.campaignCategoriesChecked.push(category);
        }
    } else {
        this.campaignCategoriesChecked.splice( this.campaignCategoriesChecked.indexOf(category), 1 );
    }
    return;
}

submit() {
    this.modalController.dismiss(this.campaignCategoriesChecked);
}

isChecked(category: CampaignCategoryInterface) {
    if (this.campaignCategoriesChecked.length === 0) {
        return false;
    }
    const findCategory = this.campaignCategoriesChecked.find(e => e.id === category.id);

    return !!findCategory;
}
```

Working but not for all cases. Sometimes I get the error : `Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'checked: true'. Current value: 'checked: false'`. For example :

1. I open popup with filters I choose last 2 categories
2. I reopen popup with filters, last 2 categories are checked
3. Now, when I try to uncheck the last categorie, both are unchecked I get the error that I wrote + the function `selectCategory()` is called twice, for both categories and I dont understand why.

Have you an idea ?